# How to put ICP cluster login in shell script

Tags: bash, ibm-cloud

I wish to put ICP cluster login command into a shell script - the problem is the 'Select an account' prompt below. Does anyone know how to circumvent that please ? Just placing a '1' at end of command doesn't work.

```
bx pr login -a https://1.2.3.4:9999 --skip-ssl-validation -u admin -p admin
```

> API endpoint: https://1.2.3.4:9999
>   Authenticating...
>   OK
>
> Select an account:
>
> 1. mycluster Account (id-mycluster-account)
>
> Enter a number>

Comment: "at end of command" how? You'd have to make it a herestring or heredoc to feed it on stdin.

Comment: To try that, `<<<"1"` if your shell is bash, or tacking `<<'EOF'` onto the line, then a new line with `1`, and then a new (unindented!) line with the string `EOF` to work on any other POSIX-y shell (specifically including `/bin/sh`)

Comment: ...if you need to actually emulate a TTY rather than feeding stdin, then we get into playing with [`expect`](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) (a TCL-based scripting language), [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (likewise, for Python) or [`EmPTY`](http://empty.sf.net/) (a tool for doing similar work in bash).

Comment: Thanks alot for that Charles - it worked a treat i.e  <<<"1"